# Thermal analysis of a step down regulator

Tags: mosfet, buck, thermal, heatsink, open-drain

[image]

[LTM8053 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTM8053-8053-1.pdf)

I tried to plot the thermal graphic (watt-celcius) for this buck converter in MATLAB. The main goal is to find losses which turn into heat. Reasons for heat most of time switching losses. How can I calculate the value of these losses in watts? I found some equations but for IGBT not MOSFET. There are also internal inductor and external components (R,C.) How can I calculate these component's losses?

In summary, I want to make some graphs like below:

[image]

Comment: All the components will have DC resistive losses. Then you've got switching losses. Those will depend heavily on the gate drive circuit and specifics of the FETs. Probably also some magnetic losses in the inductor.

Comment: The graph you show is looks mostly like the thermal resistance - that's where the linear part comes from. The slight curvature comes from rise in DC resistive losses. The graph has no meaning without indication of what the temperature applies to. Junction? Case? Ambient?